# Can I do something not `transfrom` in `map` and `flatMap` function?

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

Is `Map` function of `Optional` in Swift just used to `transform`?

If I want do something just Optional has some value, Can I Use `map` function? if not, why?

According to apples examples, we used `map` like this

```swift
let possibleNumber: Int? = Int("42")
possibleNumber.map { $0 * $0 }
```

Can I use it like this? : (If it's not proper, how to explain it)

```swift
func setImage(with data: Data?) {
   data.flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
        .map { imageView.image = $0 }
}
```

Furthermore `map` function should return a value, but why this function does not have any `warning` about not used of result ( such as `result of call map{...} is unused` ) ?

Comment: Just ignore the first code of example, whether the second code is proper is my confused

Comment: Why not implement `setImage` as: `imageView.image = data.map { UIImage(data: $0) }`

Comment: @rmaddy It's just an example code.. If `imageView` need a nonNull `UIImage`?

Comment: That's what the `??` operator is for. Use `imageView.image = data.map { UIImage(data: $0) } ?? someDefaultImage`.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. If `data` is `nil` and you don't have a default image then `image` can't be non-nil.

Comment: If your goal is to keep the original image if `data` is `nil` then you can do: `imageView.image = data.map { UIImage(data: $0) } ?? imageView.image`

Comment: “If I want do something just `Optional` has some value, can I use `map` function?” ... You can, but shouldn’t. It is intended for transforming values, is listed as such in the documentation, and the whole concept comes from functional languages where there should never be side effects. Your example is simple enough, but consider more complicated closures where the side effects might be less obvious. You (and the rest of your team) will thank yourself in the future if you avoid this altogether, making your code easier to reason about.

Comment: Another way to think about it: Consider the analogous `map` for `Array`: If it were intended to use it for code with side-effects, too, they never would have provided a `forEach` method. Stick with `if let` pattern with optionals when writing code that does anything beyond transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly *can* do it, it's just not very conventional. When people see `map`, they have a pre-conceived expectation that it'll be doing a transformation. You're violating that expectation, but there's nothing technically "wrong" about it.

Personally, I prefer using this extension:

```
extension Optional {
    /// An enum used to ensure that `ifNone` is never called before `ifSome`.
    enum IfSomeResult {
        case some
        case none

        func ifNone(_ closure: () throws -> Void) rethrows -> Void {
            switch self {
                case .some: return
                case .none: try _ = closure()
            }
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    func ifSome(then closure: (Wrapped) throws -> Void) rethrows -> IfSomeResult {
        if let wrapped = self {
            try _ = closure(wrapped)
            return IfSomeResult.some
        }
        else {
            return IfSomeResult.none
        }
    }

    func ifNone(then closure: () throws -> Void) rethrows -> Void {
        if case nil = self { try _ = closure() }
    }
}
```

And writing code like:

```
data.flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    .ifSome { imageView.image = $0 }
```

### Why doesn't it warn about an unused value?

The closure is inferred to return `Void` (the empty tuple type, whose only value is the empty tuple, `()`). The compiler never emits warnings about `Void` values being unused`. Here's an example:

```
Optional(123).map { _ in () }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And how to explain about It doesn't has any warning of I don't use `map''s result?

Comment: @Alexander, furthermore I think this question was also about why the `map` method does not display the Warning `result of call to map{} unused`. 
the map function is `@inlinable` but I cannot see `@discardableResult`. 
( and I am strarting to get interested in the answer too tbh )

Comment: @Zafir_zzf "And how to explain about It doesn't has any warning of I don't use `map''s result?" I actually have no idea! I can't explain it. Map isn't marked with `@discardableResult` https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L139-L170

Comment: @Alexander I guess the result of `Map` is a type of `()?`, this type always can not be used. So the complier don't have `warning`

Comment: `imageView.image = data.map { UIImage(data: $0) }` is so much simpler and no extension required.

Comment: @rmaddy It's semantically different. It assigns `nil` in the `nil` case, whereas the proposed code left the previous value intact in the `nil` case.

Comment: @Alexander If that's the requirement then yes, my suggestion would not be appropriate. It wasn't clear that the goal was to only modify the image if `data` isn't nil. That can be done with `imageView.image = data.map { UIImage(data: $0) } ?? imageView.image`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, the best choice depends on the exact semantics desired. The latest code you posted has yet another semantic distinction, in that it triggers `didSet`/`willSet` observers, even if the value hasn't changed

Comment: @Alexander This is off-topic but can you explain what the `Wrapped` keyword exactly is for? I can't find a site that explains this properly. A link/explanation is much appreciated :-)

Comment: @LokSN that's because it's not a keyword :) "Wrapped" is the name of Optional's sole generic type parameter. We colloquially use `T` for brevity, saying thing like `Optional<T>` or `Array<T>`, when the actually generic types names in those cases are `Optional<Wrapped>` and `Array<Element>`

Comment: @Alexander Oh! I feel dumb now :-) Thank you!

Comment: @LokSN No need. Idk how I would have looked it up if I hadn't known it already.